# Tap gesture is not working

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have added UITapGesture on UIImageView. Have added all the code. ImageView description is showing the gestures, but still it is not working.

```
@interface VideoBaseProgramEditorViewController ()<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> {

UITapGestureRecognizer* tapGesture;
}
```

...

```
 tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewTapped)];
              [tapGesture setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
              tapGesture.delegate = self;
              thumbImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
             [thumbImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    UIView *view = touch.view;
    NSLog(@"%@",view);
    return YES;
}

-(void) viewTapped {

  [self loadVideo];
}
```

**Issue:** `shouldReceiveTouch` method is also not calling.

Image view description is showing added gesture in logs.

> UIImageView: 0x7bb7b370; frame = (0 0; 736 485); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = NSArray: 0x7bc80910; layer = CALayer: 0x78f793d0

any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you also share viewTapped method?

Comment: sure. Plz check edits.

Comment: Your code is working.

Comment: it's not working in my page :( as I said even shouldReceiveTouch method not calling.

Comment: How you are adding imageView in your ViewController ? through storyboard ? or manually by code ?

Comment: through storyboard

Comment: Send your source code I will help you

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable user interaction on `UIImageView` which is disabled by default. On your `storyboard` or `xib` select your `UIImageView` and in Attribute Inspector tick the `User Interaction Enabled`.

Comment: I have enabled it in code, when I am setting a gesture on it.

Comment: Your code is working. Check if there is not any other views over  your UIImageView.

Comment: <UIImageView; frame = (0 0; 736 485); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x791057a0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b188ce0>>,
<UIActivityIndicatorView; frame = (358 233; 20 20); hidden = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM+RM+TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b1db3b0>>,
<UIButton; frame = (665 0; 70 70); hidden = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b1d77f0>>,
<UIImageView; frame = (637 10; 88 88); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM+W+RM+TM+H+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x791a96c0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b1db5d0>

Comment: this is damn simple code. still it is not working. That is why I am wondering that what's been left.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
        NSLog(@"Successfully Tap");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you link your IBOutlet `thumbImageView` ?
How do you declare your properties ?

Maybe try this following code. Work with `userInteractionEnabled` both code and xib.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITapGestureRecognizer* tapGesture;

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *thumbImageView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewTapped:)];
    _tapGesture.delegate = self;
    [_tapGesture setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    // _thumbImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES; // Uncomment if you allow interaction from code
    [_thumbImageView addGestureRecognizer:_tapGesture];
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    UIView *view = touch.view;
    NSLog(@"%@",view);
    return YES;
}

- (void)viewTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    UIView *view = sender.view;
    NSLog(@"%@",view);
}

@end
```

Comment: yes my IBOutlet is connected
 __weak IBOutlet UIImageView *thumbImageView;